# Below code are written in mvc controller, can anyone explain this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Can Anyone explain the use of the below lines in .net MVC

```
string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
_hdfcData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HDFCData>(apiResponse);
```

Comment: It is deserializing the content of the response to the object type of `HDFCData`.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

get http response message and serialize it to string

```cs
_hdfcData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HDFCData>(apiResponse);
```

deserialize the string to `HDFCData` type